# How to take all values till some defined value to change columns names in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have DataFrame like below:

```
col1()     | abr(ddd = 66, acop = 11)  | cdb()
-----------------------------------------------
111        | 222                       | 3333
```

And I need to change names of columns.

To change names of columns I woudl like to take all values before () in each column name, so I need to Data Frame like below as a result:

```
col1     | abr  | cdb
----------------------
111      | 222  | 3333
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `split` the columns on opening parenthesis with `n=1` i.e. the maximum
number of splits, and take only the first value from the list, convert it to the list of strings, then assign it back to `df.columns`:

```py
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.split('(', 1).str[0].to_list()

   col1  abr   cdb
0   111  222  3333
```

Answer (score 0):

However, you got the answer but for posterity, there is another method as well.

### Sample DataFrame:

```
print(df)
   col1()  abr(ddd = 66, acop = 11)  cdb()
0     111                       222  33333
```

### columns:

```
print(df.columns)
Index(['col1()', 'abr(ddd = 66, acop = 11)', 'cdb()'], dtype='object')
```

### Solution:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"col1()": "col1", "abr(ddd = 66, acop = 11)": "abr",  "cdb()": "cdb"}, inplace=True)

print(df)
   col1  abr    cdb
0   111  222  33333
```

### Another solution:

@ same approach which is provided in the previous answer but little shorter.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('[()]').str[0].tolist()
print(df)
   col1  abr    cdb
0   111  222  33333
```